# Somebody with chinese username (hacker?) writes files into folder "users", what's going on?

Tags: macos, security, xcode, high-sierra, hacking

I'm the single user of my personal MacBook (macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 (17D102)), using it only inside my single apartment, not inside a network, not connected to anything beside my router, and a user called "Linchengzang" has created a user folder inside my filesystem and is writing Xcode files into it.

The user is not know to the system. I never used Xcode (but I am a developer), and I didn't install any software in the last few days, but these files and folders appered within the last few hours.

It's creepy that these files have suspicios names, all related to auth things.

Can somebody please give me a hint what is going on here ?

Big thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you know what ‘ADAL’ is? Is it an app you have installed on your Mac?

Comment: ADAL is Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication Library. Are you familiar with that? Do you use Azure? Have you installed/compiled/built anything in the last few hours that may have written these files?

Comment: More a point of clarity than anything else. You say "not inside a network" and then "not connected to anything besides my router." If you are connected to your router via WiFi (or anything else) you **are** inside a network. That network is then presumably connected to the internet.

Comment: Have you set a root password? It might be wise to change all your admin passwords as well. Also agreeing with @SteveChambers, if you are connected to your router you are in a network. If you can access the internet, the internet can access you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer by myself and can reproduce the above scenario: The official wallet software of the cryptocurrency Bytecoin is creating this user and these files.